# asterisk in variable declaration in headers in obj-c

Tags: objective-c, pointers, variables

I get that asterix is for pointers, and I understand about pointers now. But I'm still not sure why when declaring a variable in a header I need to use an asterix, for example:

```
UINavigationController * navController;
```

why isn't that:

```
UINavigationController navController;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in your example:

UINavigationController * navController;

navController is a pointer to object of UINavigationController type;

and you always work with pointers using Objective-C objects, when you create new instance with:

```
[[MyClass alloc] init]
```

it returns pointer to newly created object of type MyClass i.e (MyClass *)

Answer (score 2):

In the header you are declaring the memory that needs to be allocated for an object.  You need to use the `*` operator because you only want to declare memory space for a reference/pointer to the object, and not space for the object itself.